# Can I withdraw and send another Beta version of my app again- Android?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, beta-testing

My app is on beta version on Playstore. But I found a little problem on the code later thanks to the users. I tried to delete the old beta version and upload new one but couldn't find any menu or options like that. Do you know any or do I have to wait till releasing normal version? Thanks

Comment: Just release a new beta version and your users can update... or am I overthinking this? The new beta will simply replace the old one.

Comment: wow that was easy and it worked, thanks a lot Ezekiel..

Comment: Added Exekiel;s answer as an answer rather than a comment to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

Just release a new beta version and your users can update. The new beta will simply replace the old one.